# How to test censoring patterns of two samples agree?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, survival, censoring, equivalence

I am not sure I even understood the book. I am reading Applied Survival Analysis by Hosmer, Lemeshow and May's pg 58.

The book says "Problems in study design and data collection can lead to differential effects due to censoring, and the best protection is a carefully designed study. **However, it is a good practice to examine censoring pattern in the data**."

1. How do I examine censoring pattern in the data here? Do I look at only censor data's distribution and apply some non-parametric test for agreements? Or do I look at total data including censored ones and compare distribution? I am guessing the former as the later does not make sense to me.
2. As for testing for censoring independence of groups, do I just test upon association of censoring and groups here by forming a table?
3. How do I know a study design/data collection will lead or leads to differential effects?